# Hash proof system programming implementation

Tags: programming, hash-function

Does anyone know if there is a hash proof system implementation using some programming language? Like C++, python.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and asking for several days, a conclusion can be made.

No such implementation off the shelf.

Will do it myself with OpenSSL.